# Android -- Menu items that function as tabs

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

I have several activities that inherit from a base activity with a menu like below.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent myIntent;
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            myIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.map:
            myIntent = new Intent(this, GoogleMapsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            return true;
        case R.id.art:
            myIntent = new Intent(this, ArtActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            return true;
        ...
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

This works well, but selecting a menu item starts a new instance of that activity.  How can pause() and resume() be used in conjunction with setResult() to only have one or less instance of each activity at a given time?

In an effort to be more specific, when a user comes back to a previously visited activity, it should be in the same state as they left it (like tabs).

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by configuring the [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of the activities to be singleTask.  However, as the docs point out, this may result in unexpected behavior for the user.  When the user hits back, they expect to be taken back to the previous screen they were at.  If you use this mode, make sure you test the back functionality thoroughly.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply!  This is much closer to what I was trying to accomplish.  There is one problem I'm having with the behavior.  If I go to the activity that has the main intent for the app (the one that starts on app execution) and then back to a previously opened activity, it is still creating a new instance (or at least recalling onCreate().  It doesn't do this if I navigate between non-main-activity tabs.  Any reason this would happen?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the way my onOptionsItemSelected() is implemented?

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with your main activity also being a launcher activity, but I'm not sure.  You could try creating a dummy launcher activity that just launches your main activity in onCreate..

Answer (score 0):

Use `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)` to your intent and just start the 'Activity' via `startActivity`

Comment: This solves the problem with the same exception as above.  If I go to the activity that has the main intent for the app (the one that starts on app execution) and then back to a previously opened activity, it is still creating a new instance (or at least recalling onCreate(). It doesn't do this if I navigate between non-main-activity tabs.

Comment: Are you closing the activities?